# Create CloudFormation resources in different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've a CF stack and I've defined different resources. One of these is an S3 Bucket. I need to run the stack in the `eu-west-1` region while create the bucket in the `ap-southeast-1` region. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible using the standard `AWS::S3::Bucket` in CloudFormation, since resources managed by a CloudFormation stack can only reside in the same region as the stack itself. However, you could work your way around this by using a Lambda function

Your Lambda function would have to set the `LocationConstraint` to `ap-southeast-1` when [creating the bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html). Also, you Lambda function will be responsible for updating and deleting your bucket, which can involve a bit more code.

You can wire your Lambda function to CloudFormation using [Lambda-backed Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html).

Comment: It's not clear. in this case should I create the S3 Bucket resource in CF? in other word the bucket must be created inside the lambda function or in CF?

Comment: No, the S3 bucket will not be created directly by your CF stack. Inside the CF stack, you would have a Custom Resource, which would link to the Lambda function. The Lambda function will create the Bucket.

Answer (score 5):

A single CloudFormation stack can only have resources in the single region that the stack resides.

However, using CloudFormation Stack Sets, you can create resources across multiple CloudFormation stacks in multiple regions and AWS accounts.

More information about using Stack Sets can be found in the Stack Set documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-concepts.html

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Sets doesn't meet this use case. I'll be more accurate. I need to create a Delivery Stream in Firehose. Firehose is available only in few regions. The S3 bucket must resides in the same region of the Redshift cluster where the data are stored. My Redshift cluster resides in `ap-southeast-1`. Here the reason why I wish to deploy multiple resource in multiple region in the same Stack

Comment: @Mazzy, Why does Stack Sets not meet your requirement?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein You can't use Stack Sets without AWS Organizations administrator delegation, so it's not suitable for an individual account just looking to deploy resources in another region (not sure if this what was Mazzy's situation was, but it's mine).