# Create Cloudwatch Alarm for Route53 Healthcheck Status via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I want to create a cloudwatch alarm for my Route53 Healthcheck status of certain endpoint using cloudformation template.

This is my cloudformation template for Route53 HealthCheck status:

```
EndpointHealthCheck:
  Properties:
   HealthCheckConfig:
    AlarmIdentifier:
      Name: !Ref EndpointCriticalAlarm
      Region: !Ref AWS::Region
    Type: HTTPS
    ResourcePath: /sample/path
    FullyQualifiedDomainName: sample.com
    RequestInterval: 60
    FailureThreshold: 5
```

This is my cloudwatch alarm:

```
EndpointCriticalAlarm:
 Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
 Properties:
  AlarmDescription: sample description
  AlarmName: HealthCheckAlarm
  Namespace: "AWS/Route53"
  MetricName: HealthCheckStatus
  ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
  Period: 60
  EvaluationPeriods: 1
  Statistic: Average
  Threshold: !Ref FailureThreshold
  AlarmActions:
    - !Ref AlarmSNSTopicArn
```

Is the cloudwatch alarm able to gather data from Route53 healthcheck status? Thanks

Comment: Just looking at the resource definitions they seem OK but I haven't turned to the docs to see if you left anything out. In my experience a healthcheck is able to trigger an alarm, _so are you seeing something different?_ And if yes, _what are you seeing?_

Comment: I think Cloudwatch metrics for Route53 are only available in AWS's "root region" (`us-east-1` / Northern Virginia) for now. This means you will have deploy your alarm to that region, even if your health check is deployed to a different region. This really complicates things because CloudFormation is not very well-suited for deploying stacks based on different templates to different regions and enabling them to reference each other's resources. There are ways as long as you have only one stack per template per region and manage your naming correctly, but it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the same issue and `ActionsEnabled: true` in the alarm definition fixed that

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because of the region constraints which apply to CloudFormation and HealthCheck alarms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66969674/1714171